# Using targetclient 1 cause to drop jms headers

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm using Spring jms to send jms messages to websphere mq using the target client as 1 at the destination resolver. However this causing to drop all the custom headers I've set to the jms message. When I set the target client as 0 it works perfectly bt I need to keep it at 1 for some other reason. Can somebody explain whats happening here and a possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In MQ JMS headers are implemented as properties in an MQ RFH2 header on the message. By specifying a target client of WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ (1) you're instructing the MQ JMS client to strip the RFH2 header away. Which in your case means you lose your custom headers. So by setting WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ  you're essentially opting out of this feature.

You either need to use WMQ_TARGET_DEST_JMS (0) which you know works, or find another way to pass the data in your custom headers to the receiving application.

One option if you want to continue with WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ is to include your custom headers in the message body as name/value pairs - you just need to make sure the receiving application can understand it.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to add a String header value to "usr" folder by keeping WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ ??